# app 'attaching to' hang in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I've exhausted probably all possible solutions on how to fix this :

[image]

How do I fix this? I need to run unit tests smoothly.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How long did you wait?  Sometimes it just takes a long time to attach (it annoys me too).  Does it work on the actual device?  This question is very weak on its contextual information.

Comment: Do you know if it's your app, or XCode? Try saving everything, closing and re-opening XCode. Check your Activity Monitor to see whats happening in XCode in regards to your actual computer. Something similar happened to me, and I just restarted XCode. What solutions have you tried?

Comment: Are you running Xcode 4.6.3?

Comment: @CaptJak I've tried most, like reset simulator, delete derived data, check if appname-info.plist was not in the "copy bundle resources", etc.

Comment: @robmayoff Yes. I've updated it yesterday but to no avail did the update fix it for me. any tips?

Comment: @borrrden A long time did i wait but to no avail.

Comment: Do you know if it's your app? or XCode? or your computer?

Comment: @CaptJak I don't really know who the culprit is.

Comment: There you go. Find the culprit, find your problem. Have you tried computer handling? Check your activity monitor (on your computer) and see whats going on while it hangs up at "attaching"

Comment: Does it happen with all projects, or only tests?

Comment: @Can It happens with all projects.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I commented out the hosts file, where it points localhost to 127.0.0.1, because XCode runs it by network, have you messed with the hosts file recently?

Comment: Reboot your computer, or edit your answer to provide a full list of everything you have tried WITH DETAILS. This entire comment section is becoming a Q&A for "what have you done". Tell us everything you tried so we can help you faster.

Comment: Reboot your box.  The Mac runs out of process handles and can't start the emulator processes.  There is also a process that gets hung and won't die and won't let the emulator start.  You can kill if you know how to find it, but I can't tell you without having the problem in front of me.

Comment: @Can hosts file is already normal. 127.0.0.1 already maps to localhost.

Comment: @CaptJak I've done what was stated in other posts related to the issue. no avail still.

Comment: @HotLicks yes, but still no avail.

Comment: You've probably already tried this, but -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/16840401/581994

Comment: And what about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17102268/581994

Answer (score 3):

Quick solution for this problem:

In finder press SHIFT+CMD+G and type

```
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

[image]

This opens DerivedData folder, delete all folder inside DerivedData.

Also Reset simulator's content:

```
         ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications
```

Comment: quit xcode, then delete derivedData, simulator reset..restart xcode..this must work...I did same many time and worked back

Comment: you tried changing LLDB to GDB ? that also works

Comment: yeah, it works. but i was wondering if there was any other way without having to change the scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Press simulator icon at dock
(or edit your scheme actually to "run app" not waiting for launch.)

Maybe this was fixed in latest xcode( pressing icon to resolve attaching issue), but in a bit outdated xcode this issue exists.

Edit: another solution which helped in the past:

Project > Edit Schemes
Change debugger.

Comment: Tried this but to no avail.